# Callback URL in Laravel, POST or GET?

Tags: php, laravel, api, callback

This is a newbie question but I guess it will help someone in future. Now when integrating an API that requires a callback URL, where it will send data through POST, when setting the Callback URL in Laravel as a ROUTE, should you do a POST or a GET route? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the API uses POST for the callbacks, then the route needs to except POST requests so...  use POST? When you define a route in laravel (or in any router) and set it as GET, POST, PUT, DELET or what ever, it's what type of request it accepts. So if some system needs to access a route on your page, you need to define it with the same method as they are sending.